# The portion of a question that will display under the Questions tab

Tags: feature-request

Is there a way for OP to see the portion of question that will display under Questions tab before submitting the question?

Comment: Good question! Unfortunately, I haven't any idea. Did you notice, when you posted this question, whether it displayed (assuming asking questions here is comparable to answering questions on the main site)?

Comment: I think if there were such a feature, people would often reformulate their question in a way to optimize that snippet - at the expense of making the post as a whole less readable (or at least less naturally formulated). Such optimization energy should rather be put into the title.

Comment: @Hagen: I don't completely agree. Because of the snipping, I think we should encourage users to put their questions "up top" and put the "lead up" below. It will at least save some time reading the site.